# Getting Visual Studio 2010 to retain VSS password

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I use Visual Studio 2010 with Visual SourceSafe 2005 for source control. Each developer has their own username/password for VSS access. I know how to configure Visual Studio to remember the login name but I cannot seem to find a way of remembering the password. Currently each time I open a project under source control I have to enter my password. A solution to this would save me hundreds of key presses per day!

A SourceSafe solution please - moving to VSN isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always configure VSS to use the network username for login.

To do this, open the VSS admin tool, open your VSS database and go to Tools|Options. Make sure this option is checked and you should be set.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing the other day but couldn't find the option in VS2010 - but Windows to the rescue (bear in mind that we're using TFS, but I can imagine it working for VSS too):

Windows 7 + Windows 2008 have the so called "Credential Manager" or . You can either start it via the Start Menu or via Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager.
Here you can enter a new credential via "Add a generic credential" with your username / password information and Visual Studio will happily never ask for your user/pass again.

Of course your password could then be read out by someone having access to your local system / working on your local system.